# Giving text based RPG in Python a GUI

Tags: python

I currently have a text based RPG that uses a large amount of print statements. These are only visible in my IDE, but I want others to be able to play my game in a more presentable way without needing an IDE. *Is there a way to easily display my print statements in some sort of GUI?* I was thinking of using PyGame, but I wanted to know if there were other options available, such as using HTML/CSS/JS or some kind of toolkit. Are there any tools to make this easier?

Comment: If it's text based could you just run it from the terminal?

Comment: A cool way would be to setup a [Flask](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-ii-templates) or Django server and to render an HTML page. Basically, you transform input()/print() into rendering text inside HTTP request handlers and it's done.  You can even host it online so that your friends can check it out from anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need very simple toolkit you could look at the Python bundled ones:

Text based

- `curses` - https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html

Graphical based

- `Tk` - https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html

There are many external toolkits available, such as

- `PyQt` - https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt
- `wxPython` - https://www.wxpython.org/
- `PyGTK` - https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

etc.
But they are really advanced ones.

Me personally I would stick with the bundled ones for now.

Comment: Wow thanks for all the resources! I'll check out curses, it sounds like the best option right now.

Answer (score 0):

If your using console inputs, you can use Pyinstaller with "--onefile" to build it into an .exe with its own little console. without needing python or using command prompt on the host computer, just be aware that if you want text to remain displayed when your program is due to terminate, you will need to use "input(" ") as the last line of your program so the console stays open